# Keep sorting of data.frame when using acast

Tags: r

When I use `acast`in R, the sorting of my data frame gets messed up. Imagine my data.frame looks like this

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  D  Y  0
2  E  X  0
3  C  N  0
4  B  M  0
5  A  S  0
```

doing `acast(dd, V1 ~ V2, value.var="V3", fill = 0)` will result in an ordered matrix, e.g.

```
  M N S X Y
A 0 0 0 0 0
B 0 0 0 0 0
C 0 0 0 0 0
D 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do I keep the original sorting of the data frame?

Comment: Are you sure your formula gives this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `V1` and `V2` into factors, and when you do so, make their levels the order you want.  The default ordering when making factors is to sort them, which is why you got the order you did the first time.

```
d <- data.frame(V1=c("D", "E", "C", "B", "A"), V2=c("Y","X","N","M","S"), V3=0)
d$V1 <- factor(d$V1, levels=unique(d$V1))
d$V2 <- factor(d$V2, levels=unique(d$V2))
> acast(d, V1~V2, value.var="V3", fun.aggregate=sum)
  Y X N M S
D 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 0 0
C 0 0 0 0 0
B 0 0 0 0 0
A 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Cool, this worked. Why does a factor not influence the sorting?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your followup question. They're always sorted by the order of the levels of the factor.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this :

```
m <- acast(dd, V1 ~ V2, value.var="V3", fill = 0)
m[dd$V1,dd$V2]
```

Which gives :

```
  Y X N M S
D 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 0 0
C 0 0 0 0 0
B 0 0 0 0 0
A 0 0 0 0 0
```